# Check for null entries in Java Map<T, ? extends E>

Tags: java, dictionary, java-stream

I have a `Map<String, ? extends Collection<SomeClass>>`. I would like to ensure that there are no entries where collection's size is 0. Therefore I tried `myMap.values().stream().map(Collection::size).allMatch(size -> size > 0)`. However, as it turned out, myMap contains null entries.

I wanted to check if my map contains null entries: `resourceMap.values().stream().noneMatch(null)` but I got an Exception `java.util.Objects.requireNonNull`.

I decided to do it in a relatively old fashioned way, with a `for-in` loop `for (Map.Entry<String, ? extends Collection> entry : myMap)` However, I got a compilation error telling me that foreach is not applicable to my Map.

What is an elegant way to check if all entries in my map are not null and with size > 0?

Comment: `.map(CollectionUtils::isNotEmpty)` from commons-lang

Comment: Please show your `for each` ;)

Comment: For map you should use `map.entrySet()` and then iterate on map entry objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a look at the actual method signature:

```
boolean noneMatch(Predicate<? super T> predicate)
```

You will see that `noneMatch(null)` accepts a `Predicate` instance and not an actual value. Null predicates are forbidden here.

Try:

```
boolean result = resourceMap.values().stream()
  .noneMatch(Objects::isNull)
```

You can merge those two into one chain:

```
myMap.values().stream()
  .allMatch(col -> col != null && col.size() > 0);
```

Comment: Thank you! I cannot combine it, as then if my map contains null entries, but the non-null ones have size > 0 it would evaluate to true. I will just conjunct them with classic &&.

Comment: @3yakuya sure, I get it now. I think it's doable to use one stream for that. Let me try.

Comment: @3yakuya you can simply `.allMatch(col -> col != null && col.size() > 0);`

Comment: Nice! Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

You can just check for `null`s using `myMap.values().contains(null)`—no Stream API required.

If your map was consistently using `List` or `Set`, you could also check for empty values with `myMap.values().contains(Collections.emptySet())` or `myMap.values().contains(Collections.emptyList())`, but since there is no general equality contract between arbitrary collections, that doesn’t work for your `Map<String, ? extends Collection<SomeClass>>`.

So for this specific test, you could use

```
boolean violations = myMap.values().contains(null)
                  || myMap.values().stream().anyMatch(Collection::isEmpty);
```

or

```
boolean violations = myMap.values().stream().anyMatch(col -> col==null || col.isEmpty());
```

---

When you want to iterate with a `for` loop, you have to specify a Collection view over the `Map`, e.g.

```
Map<String, ? extends Collection<SomeClass>> myMap;
…
for (Map.Entry<String, ? extends Collection<?>> entry: myMap.entrySet())
    // loop body
```

or, much better for this use case

```
for(Collection<?> value: myMap.values())
    if(value == null || value.isEmpty())
        // violation detected, perform your action
```